# taylor expansion of complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I have been looking at certain Taylor expansions of the exponential function

$$ e^{iy} = 1 + iy + \dfrac{\theta_1 y^2}{2},$$
$$ e^{iy} = 1 + iy - \dfrac{y^2}{2} + \dfrac{\theta_2|y|^3}{3!},$$
which hold for any real number $y$ with some $\theta_1=\theta_1(y)$, $\theta_2=\theta_2(y)$ such that $|\theta_1|\leq 1$ and $|\theta_2|\leq 1$.

Could anyone explain how one gets to both? and if their is a general rule one should consider. Thanks!

Comment: Consider extraction $\theta_1=2(e^{iy}-1-iy)/(y^2)$ for example...

Comment: I can see that it is the same question, i am just not sure if i understand their answers. Thanks for the link tho!

Comment: Come on, this *is* Taylor's formula, to orders $1$ and $2$.

Comment: hey @YvesDaoust,  i see that. So, the $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are to give us equality i suppose? What about the $|y|^3$ term.

Comment: The remainder terms are standard, nothing more to say. (The absolute value is optional.)